# Social networking site: anonymous first, claim later

Tags: frameworks, openid, social-networking

One of the great features of *StackOverflow* is that you can ask a question or answer a question without signing up, then claim your activity later. It's perfect because you engage people right away without *any* barriers to entry.

Are there any *Social Networking frameworks* out there in **any language** with **any data backend** (relational or non-relational) that support this behavior along with OpenID?

Comment: This was a great lead. If you answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- OSQA.net - Python & Django
- Shapado - Ruby on Rails
- Question2Answer - PHP

Comment: I am using question2answer to set up a Q&A web site. It is very easy to install and administration. But its social characteristic is weakness.

Answer (score 0):

As requested in one of the comments:
www.osqa.net

(But I do not really deserve this ...)